# Split string by ". " except when after a number

Tags: c#, split

I want to split strings, by phrases, and to do that I'm doing this:

```
string.Split(new[] { ". ", "? ", "! " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The thing is my string sometimes catch that after a number, when it has different points, and I want to separate by before the number, and not after, if it is possible.

original:

> Com um processo de agendamento de não mais que 60 segundos, um
>   pagamento seguro, garantia de qualidade, a Wegho torna-se o meio mais
>   simples e conveniente de poder agendar serviços para o seu lar.
>   Entenda-se lar como a simbiose perfeita do ativo físico “casa” e do
>   ativo “emocional” família. Preparado para ter um parceiro de
>   excelência nos serviços que precisa para o seu lar? 1.    Explore os
>   nossos serviços em Wegho.om 2.    Selecione o serviço que pretende.
>   Através do código postal verificaremos se estamos presentes na área
>   que pretende 3.   Escolha uma hora

result:

> Com um processo de agendamento de não mais que 60 segundos, um
>   pagamento seguro, garantia de qualidade, a Wegho torna-se o meio mais
>   simples e conveniente de poder agendar serviços para o seu lar.
>
> Entenda-se lar como a simbiose perfeita do ativo físico “casa” e do
>   ativo “emocional” família.
>
> Preparado para ter um parceiro de excelência nos serviços que precisa
>   para o seu lar?
>
> 1. Explore os nossos serviços em Wegho.om
> 2. Selecione o serviço que pretende. Através do código postal verificaremos se estamos presentes na área que pretende
> 3. Escolha uma hora

And also, is it possible to keep the caught separating characters from which the string was split in the strings?

Comment: The result is not the result which you get from your `string.Split`, is it your desired result? It's a completely different formatted string and not a `string[]`. How is that related your `string.Split` at all?

Comment: What if you had a sentence that ends with a number? Example: "You are number 6. - I am not a number!"

Comment: @lloyd I've tried using regex but I'm not comfortable with it since I haven't used it previously.

Comment: It seems you are trying to do some sort of auto-format. I guess you'll need to add more criteria to the different cases.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The result is what I would like to have, being that every different line break would mean a different string in an array yes, that was just the example of how I would like to separate the phrases.

Comment: @Fildor I don't expect to have any such value in my strings, so I guess it would split that into two strings:
"You are number "
"6. - I am not a number!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try regular expressions:

```
string pattern = @"([^\d][.!?][ ])";
string substitution = @"$1\n\n";
string input = @"Com um processo de agendamento de não mais que 60 segundos, um pagamento seguro, garantia de qualidade, a Wegho torna-se o meio mais simples e conveniente de poder agendar serviços para o seu lar. Entenda-se lar como a simbiose perfeita do ativo físico “casa” e do ativo “emocional” família. Preparado para ter um parceiro de excelência nos serviços que precisa para o seu lar? 1. Explore os nossos serviços em Wegho.om. 2. Selecione o serviço que pretende. Através do código postal verificaremos se estamos presentes na área que pretende. 3. Escolha uma hora";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

Check the full [code](https://regex101.com/r/VWE2ar/2) and [result](https://regex101.com/r/VWE2ar/2/codegen?language=csharp).

However, the split will work inside the bullets also. And you will need to end your bullet content with a dot also.

Comment: This works for I want to do, thanks! The only thing now is that after that, I can't split the string into an array catching the "\n\n" characters... I'm trying doing it like this, but I don't know if I need to account for something else, \n\n being a special character: 
var resultSeparated = result.Split(new[] { "\n\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: But if you need to split it just use `Regex.Matches` instead of `Regex.Replace`. See the code at https://regex101.com/r/VWE2ar/4/codegen?language=csharp.

Comment: Regex.Matches gives me the characters found with the regex, not the separated phrases. And Regex.Replace was perfect (if I could afterwards split the string) because it wouldn't remove any characters.

Comment: Great idea, thanks! It works perfectly to what I want now!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to split strings the way you do currently, and then go through the resultant list again, re-combining number-only strings with strings that immediately follow them:

```
var tokens = string.Split(new[] { ". ", "? ", "! " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var res = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < tokens.Length ; i++) {
    var tok = tokens[i];
    int ignore;
    if (i != tokens.Length-1 && int.TryParse(tok, out ignore)) {
        tok += ". "+tokens[++i];
    }
    res.Add(tok);
}
```

Note that your overall approach is fragile, because it is not possible to tell if a numeric part is a "bullet number" or not without some user mark-up to help you identify numbered bullets.